# How can I modify search service to include words that could be like "una" in Spanish?

Tags: search

I have a problem searching for someone in SharePoint 2010. In my organization there is a person whose surname is "Uña" (nail in english) but cannot be found in search. When I write his surname in search textbox returns 0 results. When I user another usual surname like "López" returns a lot of results. If I search for a complete name + surname returns only one result.

Search service are properly configured and there are a lot of more things like documents to search for.

UPDATE - 01/18/2012
I realized that this happens when the search is on "k" parameter instead of using a metadata property that find the person correctly. For example, if the query string is like 'k=*uña*' don't return any result but when is like 'k=personname:"*uña*"' returns some results.

My suspect is that the search engine thinks that when someone write "uña" means "una" and, in Spanish, this word is an article so there isn't a word to search for because articles are so common. I made some test using other words with "ñ" and return correct results.

Does anybody know how can I add some words to avoid these comparation?

Answer (score 3):

The noise word file is blocking the word "una". The noise word file can be found here:

\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Data\Office Server\Config\noiseesn.txt

Try removing una and reindexing.

Comment: Thanks for your response but what I want to do is the opposite, add "uña" to some list to index it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Out of interest, what happens if you search for "uña" e.g  include the double quotes around the word?

Comment: Doesn't work. Please, show the update I made. When I use a metadata property the search is correct but when is general search results are not returned.

Comment: OK, I'm guessing now. I wonder if it's to do with page content character encoding. What happens if you write "uña" into a Word document and index that. Is it found in the search?

Comment: Answering your question, I created a list and added some items with 'ñ' and some other clean of strange characters. I created a doc library and inserted a document named 'uña' that contains a lot of words 'uña', as well. I reindex the content and when I search for 'uña' appear the item list but not the document.